# php how do I make a textbox unchangeable or passive and a syntax error

Tags: php

ive been all around trying to fix the code but i still get an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'userfirstName' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/crosswayprinting/public_html/ztest2/functions/shop.php on line 66

here's the code btw
whats my mistake :/ ?

```
 <?php if($user_home->is_logged_in()){
    echo ' 





<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Place an Order</h2>
<div class="text-center" style="input, select, textarea{
    color: #000;
}">


</div><BR>

      <form role="form" class="userTrans" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="OrderInsert" name="act_userTrans">


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="typeofservice">Select Type of Service</label>
  <select id="typeofservice" class="form-control" name="typeofservice">
        <option value="Tarpaulin">Tarpaulin</option>
        <option value="Rush ID">Rush ID</option>
        <option value="Photocopy">Photocopy</option>
        <option value="Graphic Layout">Graphic Layout</option>
        <option value="Invitation">Invitation</option>
        <option value="Panaflex">Panaflex</option>
        <option value="Signages">Signages</option>
        <option value="Stickers">Stickers</option>
        <option value="Sintra board">Sintra board</option>
        <option value="Large Format Photo">Large Format Photo</option>
        <option value="PVC ID">PVC ID</option>
        <option value="Lamination">Lamination</option>
        <option value="Bag Tags">Bag Tags</option>
        <option value="Notary Public">Notary Public</option>
        <option value="Scan">Scan</option>
    </select>
    </div>



     <div class="form-group">
  <label for="templateselect">Template Selection</label>
  <select id="templateselect" class="form-control" name="templateselect">
        <option value="Own Made Template">Own Made Template</option>
        <option value="Pre-made Template">Pre-made Template</option>

    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">More details about your order</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderdetails" name="orderdetails">
  </div>

     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text"> Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userfirstName']; ?> " class="form-control" id="customer" name="customer">
    </div>
  /* this is the code btw what makes it an error, i am trying to
```

echo a customer's name and make it Passive or uneditable textbox so it can 
register to my orderlist  to whom ordered */

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default userTrans">Submit</button>
</form>


    ';
                    }


else{
                        echo '


                       <center>  Please Login to Place an Order </center>
';}



                    ?>
```

Comment: `}">` <<< right there. You forgot something important.

Comment: my bad uhm, i dont exactly got what i forgot to about that part :ll
i tried adding ; or removing the line of that code  what seems to be missing ><

Comment: oh and  what makes the error btw is this one
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="text"> Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userfirstName']; ?> " class="form-control" id="customer" name="customer">
    </div>


it works when its out of the  user logged in Php line  but when its under that , this results an error... x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the echo statements wrapping your HTMl. There's no need, just escape out of the PHP interpreter and print your HTML. Then you won't get an error when you're doing `<?php echo $row['userFirstName']; ?>`....Something like this:

```
<?php if($user_home->is_logged_in()){ ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Place an Order</h2>

            <form role="form" class="userTrans" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" value="OrderInsert" name="act_userTrans">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="typeofservice">Select Type of Service</label>
                    <select id="typeofservice" class="form-control" name="typeofservice">
                        <option value="Tarpaulin">Tarpaulin</option>
                        <option value="Rush ID">Rush ID</option>
                        <option value="Photocopy">Photocopy</option>
                        <option value="Graphic Layout">Graphic Layout</option>
                        <option value="Invitation">Invitation</option>
                        <option value="Panaflex">Panaflex</option>
                        <option value="Signages">Signages</option>
                        <option value="Stickers">Stickers</option>
                        <option value="Sintra board">Sintra board</option>
                        <option value="Large Format Photo">Large Format Photo</option>
                        <option value="PVC ID">PVC ID</option>
                        <option value="Lamination">Lamination</option>
                        <option value="Bag Tags">Bag Tags</option>
                        <option value="Notary Public">Notary Public</option>
                        <option value="Scan">Scan</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="templateselect">Template Selection</label>
                    <select id="templateselect" class="form-control" name="templateselect">
                        <option value="Own Made Template">Own Made Template</option>
                        <option value="Pre-made Template">Pre-made Template</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">More details about your order</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderdetails" name="orderdetails">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text"> Customer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userfirstName']; ?> " class="form-control" id="customer" name="customer">
                   <!-- now the above won't give an error -->
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default userTrans">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- Do not use center tags when you're using bootstrap framework -->
    <!--<center>  Please Login to Place an Order </center>-->
    <div class="text-center"> Please Login to Place an Order </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also what's going on with your inline styles? That's not how this works:

```
<div class="text-center" style="input, select, textarea{
    color: #000;
}">
```

Just move that CSS somewhere else. You can't use targeted selectors within the `style=""` tag, only relevant CSS.

Comment: oh my it worked well!   i see :OOO  kindof learned the echo somewhere but this one is good and i can see the codes in their own coloreds :3    and yeah still not really get the drift of bootstraps :/